# How do I fix this undefined variable error for a php contact form?

Tags: php, forms, ajaxform

I'm getting blank emails everyday in around the same hour, and getting undefined variable error in my php mailer, what do I need to do to fix it?
I have in my page 2 different forms.

I tried to add this to my php: if (isset($_POST)){}, After I add it I still got blanks but the error now is for different line. Now my error is for the $email_subject $email_body lines 35,36.

This is the error log:

[19-Sep-2019 19:26:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: name in /home/user/public_html/mail/mailer.php on line 35
[19-Sep-2019 19:26:50 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: name in /home/user/public_html/mail/mailer.php on line 36

My PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}

if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
}

if (isset($_POST['lname'])) {
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}

if (isset($_POST['tel'])) {
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
}

if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
    $address = $_POST['address'];
}

if (isset($_POST['project'])) {
    $project = $_POST['project'];
}

if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
}

    $to = '';
    $email_subject = "$fname $lname $name Contact You from :";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.<br/>"."Here are the details:<br/><br/> Name: $fname $lname $name<br/> Email: $email<br/> Phone: $tel<br/> Address: $address<br/> Project: $project<br/> Message:\n$message";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $name = $fname = $lname = $email = $tel = $address = $project = $message = '';

    if(mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers)) {
            echo "OK";
        }
```

Comment: You need default values for those variables then override it if one is submitted in the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the error message I would guess that not all fields are being filled out so you'll want to default those variables before checking if they are set:

```
$name = $fname = $lname = $email = $tel = $address = $project = $message = '';
```

Comment: So I just need to add this in my PHP?

Comment: If you add this above what you have posted I think you will no longer get the undefined variable message.

Comment: I still get the error in the same lines: email_subject, email_body, the error is for the name: Undefined variable: name

Comment: Please edit your post to include the error message in it's entirety.

Comment: I just did it now

Comment: Ok I see, you need to add what I gave you at the top, ie before the first `if` statement.

Comment: Like this https://3v4l.org/QcNA4

Comment: I got it thank you so much, now I won't get the blank emails anymore?